# Add Icon font in wpf

Tags: wpf, font-face

I want to add custom icon in WPF. I use `entypo` and `Font-Awesome`.

I add this pakage in solution and use it in XAML.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontAwesome">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="fonts/FontAwesome.ttf" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<TextBlock Text="&#xf01a;" Style="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}" />
```

But don't show Icon.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="&#xf01a;" TextElement.FontFamily="fonts/FontAwesome.ttf" Style="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}" />` is this works fine? is the font family is applied correctly?

Comment: Thanks, I use this but don't show icon and  show a rectangle, I add Fonts folder(.eot,.svg,.ttf,.woff) to solution, Do i have any special settings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your font is added as a resource. Then, use the following string:

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#FontAwesome" />
```

In the string above, I'm assuming that the font's name (**not** the font's filename) is FontAwesome.

Comment: Thanks, I Go to property and choose action Embedded Resource for font file. and use this value, but don't show:(

Comment: Thanks a lot, I remove font and add again, and use this value, it is ok :)

Comment: Don't choose `Embedded Resource`, it is not supported in this case. Should select `Resource` instead, though `Content` is another possible choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Below structure if the font resource is in your solution folder,

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="../fonts/FontAwesome.ttf" />
```

Comment: Using relative paths is generally a bad idea - it relies on the location of your XAML files.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, i agree with that.. but i mean not to confuse him a lot.. Just it is an another way..

Comment: What's your mean of 'font resource', I download fonts of http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome and and fonts folder to solution.

Comment: It seems the problem with the Font file, I tried with the same font file downloaded from that location, no change in the font.. Better to check the font file with any word processing software and make use here..