# Changing Font Icon in WPF using Font Awesome

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts, font-awesome

I am making use of Font Awesome's icons to render basic font images within my C# WPF application. During run-time when I attempt to alter the TextBlock to display a different font icon but the unicode representation is displayed instead of the font icon.

I have created a sample application to display this. When either of the buttons are clicked, it replaces the TextBlock's Text property with the unicode for the respective icon. There is a Resources folder in the project which has the [FontAwesome.ttf](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) font file as a Build Resource which the The TextBlock's FontFamily property references.

Here's my sample application's source code:

Code-Behind:

```
namespace FontAwesomeTest
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGlass_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tblkFontIcon.Text = "&#xf000;";            
    }

    private void btnMusic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tblkFontIcon.Text = "&#xf001;";
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tblkFontIcon.Text = "&#xf002;";
    }        
}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FontAwesomeTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Font Awesome Test Window" Height="300" Width="330" Name="FontAwesomeTestWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="btnGlass" Height="35" Width="85" Click="btnGlass_Click" >Glass</Button>
    <Button Name="btnMusic" Grid.Column="1" Height="35" Width="85" Click="btnMusic_Click">Music</Button>
    <Button Name="btnSearch" Grid.Column="2" Width="85" Height="35"  Click="btnSearch_Click">Search</Button>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome">&#xf000;</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome">&#xf001;</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome">&#xf002;</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="tblkFontIcon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="64" FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">&#xf011;</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I used the following tutorial to incorporate Font Awesome into my application http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634540/Using-Font-Icons

So in essence, how can I change the Icon but have an Icon display - not Unicode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need this code. It would save you from typing unicodes manually: https://github.com/fzany/Font-Awesome-Cheat-Charp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## UPDATE

I found a different post for this topic -- 
[Add Icon font in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374349/add-icon-font-in-wpf)
I think this should be more likely to what you want.

> Make sure your font is added as a resource. Then, use the following
>   string:
>
> ```
> <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#FontAwesome" />
> ```
>
> In the string above, I'm assuming that the font's name (**not** the
>   font's filename) is FontAwesome.

You just need to:

1. Add the Font to your project, let's say you put them in to a folder "fonts"
2. Change the Build Action to *Resource* **not** *Embedded Resource*
3. Add your style to set the font family like the code snip above, and set the `TextBlock.Text` to the icon you like and apply the style to the TextBlock.

If you want change the icon by updating the `TextBlock.Text` property, you should set the `Text` property with the supported unicode string.

Try something like

```
 tblkFontIcon.Text = "\uf000";
```

rather than

```
tblkFontIcon.Text = "&#xf000;";
```

## If your're using the code from [Using Font Icons](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634540/Using-Font-Icons)

then you probably missed the "How It Works" section in that post.
You should use that markup extension, rather than using the TextBlock.Text property.

In his sample code:

```
<RibbonButton Label="Import data" 
  LargeImageSource="{WpfTools:ImageFromFont Text=&#xf01a;, 
  FontFamily=/RibbonFontIconSample;component/Resources/#FontAwesome, Brush=Brown}" />
```

pay attention to the `WpfTools:ImageFromFont`, it is the [Markup Extention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254(v=vs.110).aspx), it allows xaml parser to convert the

```
{WpfTools:ImageFromFont Text=&#xf01a;, 
      FontFamily=/RibbonFontIconSample;component/Resources/#FontAwesome, Brush=Brown}
```

to an  `ImageSource` and assigned to the `LargeImageSource` property.

So in your xaml, you could replace the `TextBlock` with an `Image`, then it should be something like:

```
<Image Source="{WpfTools:ImageFromFont Text=&#xf000;, 
      FontFamily=/RibbonFontIconSample;component/Resources/#FontAwesome, Brush=Brown}" />
```

If you want to change the Icon, you will have to change the `ImageSource` yourself, just follow the [Using Font Icons](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634540/Using-Font-Icons) to create your own method, or simply copy the following code from that tutorial.

```
private static ImageSource CreateGlyph(string text, 
        FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, 
        FontStretch fontStretch, Brush foreBrush)
{
    if (fontFamily != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
        GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;
        if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No glyphtypeface found");

        ushort[] glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
        double[] advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
        {
            ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];
            glyphIndexes[n] = glyphIndex;
            double width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * 1.0;
            advanceWidths[n] = width;
        }

        GlyphRun gr = new GlyphRun(glyphTypeface, 0, false, 1.0, glyphIndexes,
                                    new Point(0, 0), advanceWidths, 
                                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
        GlyphRunDrawing glyphRunDrawing = new GlyphRunDrawing(foreBrush, gr);
        return new DrawingImage(glyphRunDrawing);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Firstly - thanks for the speedy response! The Update you provided is how I am currently using Fonts in my WPF application. As the question states, it currently works but displays Unicode when I change the Text property even if I change it to the same Unicode. I tried to include images of this but don't have enough 'street cred'. As for the Using Font Icons part, I can't figure out how to use it for changing the Icon at Runtime as my need requires. I can get it to work during Design/Build time.

Comment: I think you should set the text with a unicode string rather than set it with "&#xf000;".

Comment: I've updated, and you could follow that code to change your TextBlock.Text to another unicode string, and that should work.

Comment: because "&#xf000;" is an xaml "version" unicode, the xaml parser translates it into the corresponding unicode string which is "\uf000" in c# and set that to the `tblkFontIcon.Text`.

Answer (score 30):

Font Awesome has NuGet packages named **FontAwesome.UWP** and **FontAwesome.WPF**. Just download  one of this.

[image: NuGet Packages for Font Awesome]

If you will use a icon import follow namespace into your XAML code:

```xml
xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
```

Use it into your button like this:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btnButton">
    <Button.Content>
        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="LongArrowLeft"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And finally in your C# code behind:

```cs
using FontAwesome.WPF; // on the top of the code
btnButton.Content = FontAwesomeIcon.LongArrowRight;
```

Comment: This is a very nice way how it becomes Handy to use fontawesome.

Comment: For the same XAML, I had to use the following code behind:
`(btnButton.Content as ImageAwesome).Icon = FontAwesomeIcon.LongArrowRight;`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful steps. What all other posts left out was "If you will use a icon import follow namespace into your XAML code:". or your markup would not build/compile.

Comment: How do you set image sources when using this package?

Comment: @paul what do you mean? It's an icon font.

Comment: The answers above show how to use the base font as an image source which is something I need to do a lot. I would assume there is some way to accomplish this with the nugget package but I cannot figure out how to do it. It is pretty rare that I actually get to use the XAML controls from font awesome.

Comment: @paul: It's indeed a XAML control. But in code behind of the nuget it's possible that it's using an `Image` control. It's also mutch easier to use the FontAwesome XAML controls.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and very easy:

You should install fontawesome font on your system use it as follows

```
<Button Content="&#xf0e4;" FontFamily="FontAwesome" FontSize="32" />
```

How to compose icon, {&#x}{FontAwesome icon code} e.g &#xf2b9 for address book

To find the list of codes goto [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) or [astronaut web](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)