# Use icon fonts in Windows Universal apps

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, icon-fonts

Since Windows 10 has .NET introduced the property [`FontIcon.Glyph`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon.glyph). If you add code below to your xaml page if gives me next char <kbd>Σ</kbd>.

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Candara" Glyph="&#x03A3;"/>
```

So I was thinking can you add an other icon font like Font Awesome or Icomoon info your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've download a font, added into my solution and I use this code:

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="ms-appx:/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome"  Glyph="&#xF055;" Foreground="Black"/>
```

what results into this:

[image]

Comment: Did you download font awesome from NuGet?

Comment: For this solution, nope, I didn't download it from NuGet. For my future and current solutions I've found that NuGet package and I use that. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108181/changing-font-icon-in-wpf-using-font-awesome/36678831#36678831)