# Add own glyph to uwp project

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm working on my Pivot header (UWP-Project) and wanted to add a custom glyph:
From [here:](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/PhoneCall/cs/MainPage.xaml)

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81C;" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
```

Now I want to use custom (or other Glyphs) for example from Fontawesome.

Here the steps:

1. Added fontawesome.ttf to my project
2. Changed `FontFamily="Segoe.."` to  `FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome"`
3. Changed Glyph to `Glyph="&#xf09e;"`

But instead of the Glyph I'm getting just a empty rectangle. What did I do wrong? Is it maybe not possible in UWP-Projects? [This solution here did not help me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108181/changing-font-icon-in-wpf-using-font-awesome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Changed FontFamily="Segoe.." to FontFamily="../Resources/#FontAwesome"

This is where the 2nd part is wrong. What you need is `FontFamily="ms-appx:///Path/To/Font/Font.ttf#FontName"` - you only have the "#FontName" part.