# Is there a way to get Font Awesome fa-pulse icons in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, animation, font-awesome

I am using spinning icons from Font Awesome in WPF application but would like instead to use the pulsed icons, instead of spinning. (See http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated). All the examples show how to do it in CSS. Is there a way with XAML?

Comment: For reference, [pulse animation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877737/advanced-xaml-animation-effects-pulse-marching-ants-rotations-alerts/25978608#25978608).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this link will help you
https://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/01/07/using-fontawesome-with-wpf/

Also, [Changing Font Icon in WPF using Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108181/changing-font-icon-in-wpf-using-font-awesome)