# How to change Fontawesome.wpf Icon in c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, font-awesome

I'm fairly new to programming in wpf, so this might be pretty basic, but I have no Idea how to change a FontAwesome Icon of a button dynamically (in c# code). I use the nuget package as described in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678831/13634159). However the last part:

> And finally in your C# code behind:
>
> ```
> using FontAwesome.WPF; // on the top of the code
> btnButton.Content = FontAwesomeIcon.LongArrowRight;
> ```

is not working for me, as it only shows the text "LongArrowRight" after clicking the button.

This is my code:

```
<Window
...
xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click">
        <Button.Content>
            <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Play"/>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

```
using FontAwesome.WPF; // at the top

private bool running = false;
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (running) 
     {
         running = false;
         btnPlay.Content = FontAwesomeIcon.Play;
     }
     else
     {
          running = true;
          btnPlay.Content = FontAwesomeIcon.Stop;
     }
}
```

As already stated when the button is clicked it does not show the Icon but only the text "Stop" and when pressed again "Play".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FontAwesomeIcon` is enum. When you assign enum value to Button.Content it will be displayed as text.

You need to assign `ImageAwesome` element to Content:

```
btnPlay.Content = new ImageAwesome { Icon = FontAwesomeIcon.LongArrowRight };
btnPlay.Content = new ImageAwesome { Icon = FontAwesomeIcon.Play };
btnPlay.Content = new ImageAwesome { Icon = FontAwesomeIcon.Stop };
```