# WPF binding font code start with '&#' not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an icon font file. I am trying to use it as a fontfamily in my WPF app.

I add it to the resource dictionary as follows:

```xml
 <FontFamily x:Key="IconFont">/MyApp;Component/Assets/Font/#iconfont</FontFamily>
```

There is a TextBlock control in MainView.xaml. I bind its Text with the *Name* property of a model.

```xml
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFont}" Text="{Binding Name}/>"
```

*Name* has value "&#xe689;". The result is that the TextBlock does display the icon but the value string. While if I directly set the Text with the code:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="&#xe689;"/>
```

And it works well.

How can I fix the binding?

Comment: hhh I found the similar question alredy has anwsers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108181/changing-font-icon-in-wpf-using-font-awesome?rq=2